# Element constant under field automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I apologize in advance for this embarrassingly stupid question, but sadly I need it **now** and don't have the time to think about it myself.

So here it is:

---

If $E \supset F$ is a field extension and $\alpha \in E$, for which the following holds
$$\phi(\alpha) = \alpha \quad \text{ for all automorphisms $\phi$ on } E \; \text{ with } \; \phi(\beta) = \beta \; \forall \beta \in F\, .$$
can we conclude that $\alpha \in F$? Or, at least for special cases like $F = \mathbb{Q}$ etc.?

---

Comment: We can conclude this only if $E/F$ is a normal extension. But there exist non-normal extensions, so the answer is no in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Crostul's comment:

Take $F = \mathbb{Q}$, $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Then any $F$-automorphism of $E$ must send $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to a root of $x^3 - 2$; but there is only one such in $E$, namely $\sqrt[3]{2}$. So there are no non-trivial $F$-automorphisms of $E$.

Comment: I've just seen the fundamental theorem of Galois theory for the first time and what "normal extension" means... I see *that's* what it is all about...